# How FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject work internally?

Tags: c#, clone

My question is relatively simple, i've the sensation that the method GetUninitializedObject( type) do not generate a new instance of a given type without call any constructor but generate a new Object that act like the correct ones (has the same structure) and apparently has the same type (but internally remain an Object).

I say that because recently i've try to clone a Form.Button using GetUninitializedObject to generate the new instances of the types i need during that operation (i operate recursively on the source object), my result has the correct structure (and immediate windows also say it has the correct type ) but if i try to do MyForm.Components.Add ( clonedButton) i receive an exception with message : "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'ControlCollection'" (but i've checked the clonedButton type is Button and its inheritances are correct too, manually i've check almost all the structures ,inside the cloned button, and match to the source Button object and i've accessed both pubblic and private fields).

So this is the why of my question (because i had a similar issue in javascript when, in the same clonation context i generate object form base Object and then add field with the right name and structure, the compiler discover my trick watching what is the called constructor of each instance, so i've supposed it could be a similar situation), if anyone can explain me the magics behind the GetUninitializedObject() it should help much ( thanks in advance).

Comment: I'm sure you couldn't cast a button to a ControlCollection either ;) Show the problematic line of code please.

Comment: It heavily breaks the rules that applies to any code you could ever write yourself in C#.  It creates an object without calling the constructor.  Very big no-no in managed code, required to support binary de-serialization.

Comment: @Vitor you are right, i mistyped the method name into question's body

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> (but internally remain an Object)

No, they don't. You've come up with a reasonable explanation for the behaviour you're seeing, but that isn't the right explanation.

The `Button` you get from `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(Button))` is a real `Button` and behaves like any other `Button` in all aspects other than that its constructor hasn't been called. The problem is that `Button` isn't designed to work when its constructor isn't called, and your attempt to fake it isn't close enough to the real thing.

You can see that the button is a real `Button` by explicitly calling the constructor on the uninitialised object:

```
var button = (Button)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(Button));
var constructor = typeof(Button).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
constructor.Invoke(button, null);
```

and you will be able to do everything with this button that you could otherwise do.